# For rendering image data:image/png;base64 is better OR not?

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on minimizing site execution time by minifying my source code, image rezising, proper image extensions, avoiding redirects and much more.
    I just want to ask you guys whether it is better to use data:image/png;base64 instead of giving static image source path for rendering image ?
    If base64 is better then could you please give me reason also ?

Comment: Better from what perspective? Is an apple better than an orange?

Comment: @zerkms Apple and only apple!